# Best user interaction to sort the elements of a UITableView'section

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting

In my app I have a grouped UITableView with 2 sections. I have to sort the elements of the second section. What'is the best user interaction to achieve it?

Comment: You should to add UISegmentedControl. And reloadData any time this control selectedIndex changed

Comment: Please explain. Why is user interaction required to sort the elements?

Comment: The table has more columns (a custom cell with three columns) and the user have to choose to sort the table by a column and by an order (ascending o descending).

Answer (score 0):

Sorting involves reloading of the table,But if you want to sort second section alone Seperate button to sort the ssection is a preferrable choicea nad can be included in the header section of tableview.

If you want the whole table to sort you can act more innovative like gestures or button press or even shake gesture.